# So far, expect to only make (1099) income in Q1 of 2014... What's my estimated liability?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, self-employment

I've earned a significant amount of 1099 income (self-employed) in the first quarter of 2014 (through 3/31/2014), but as of now, I have no idea what (if anything) I will earn for the rest of the year. How should I handle this situation to avoid penalties? I know you can use the "annualized method" and pay taxes on what you earned per quarter. Under this method, if I earn $0 in the second quarter, would I just not send in a voucher? What if I don't earn any additional income until the 4th quarter? Would I just send no voucher for Q2 and Q3?

Thank you for any tips you may have.

Comment: What is 'significant?' In finance, that's a word with no meaning. The Q1 number and general forecast for the year will help you get a good answer.

Comment: $25K.  It's very hard for me to estimate the income for the rest of the year (it could be $0)

Comment: What was your total tax in 2013?  If you had less tax liability last year than you expect to have this year (i.e. less than or around $25K in income), you could just use that number. From pub 505:  "General rule. The total amount you must pay 
is the smaller of:
1. 90% of your total expected tax for 2014, or
2. 100% of the total tax shown on your 2013 
return. Your 2013 tax return must cover all 
12 months."

Comment: @PhilSandler - you have a good answer right there. Too good for just a comment.

Answer (score 2):

What was your total tax in 2013?

If you had less tax liability last year than you expect to have this year (i.e. less than or around $25K in income), you could just use that number.

From [Publication 505](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p505.pdf):

> General rule. The total amount you must pay is the smaller of:
>
> 1. 90% of your total expected tax for 2014, or
> 2. 100% of the total tax shown on your 2013 return. Your 2013 tax return must cover all 12 months.